# Ubuntu set permissions for future created files

Tags: 14.04, chmod

I create a file host.txt and add some data

I debug PHP for 3 hours, only to know that PHP couldn't write to the file. **How can I set default 775 permissions on all files that are created  from now on on that folder**?

```
sudo groupadd powerusers
sudo usermod -a -G powerusers richard
sudo usermod -a -G powerusers nginx
sudo usermod -a -G powerusers php-fpm
usermod -a -G powerusers root
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/public_html
sudo chgrp -R powerusers /var/www/public_html
chown -R nginx:powerusers /var/www/public_html
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/public_html
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: "How can I set default 775 permissions on all files that are created from now on?" you do not want that. Trust me on that one. 750 for dirs and 640 for files (0 for others as you should use user or group to make it available for writing and reading). A "host.txt" should not be executable as it holds plain text and not something to execute

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to not set 775 as default. But if you really want to you can either use `umask` which will show you your current default and lets you set a new default.

Or you'll use this: `chmod 775 filename.txt>>!#:2` from now on for files you are certain that should have these access rights.

I would advice you to adjust the permissions individually.

Stole this from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342371/single-command-to-create-a-file-and-set-its-permission

Hope that helps!

@Edit: `umask 0002` ("Default is 0022, If I am not mistaken")

Comment: Can you plerase provice an example code umask?

Comment: There you go, I've edited it. `umask 0775` should do it. Hope that helps.

You can use `man umask` to bring up the man-page and find out more about the command. As you should be able to tell its just like chmod, it uses octal codes to determine permissions. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask

Comment: I cant afford to sert the permissiopns individually
I need to put a chmod for all files in that follder, including future ones

Comment: That information helps a lot. So you want all files created in that folder and below to have 0755? I can't think of an easy way to do that.

You could run an Cronjob every minute setting all files in that directory to 755 with chmod. Would that do the trick?

Comment: @Patient32Bit umask 0775 will not set 775 permissions to a file. 0022 wil set 644 to a file and 755 for a directory. I think umask 0775 wil set 001 for files and 002 for directories. Read this https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html.

Comment: Yeah, i was mind-flooded and switched up 0002 and 0022 and 755.

`( crontab -l ; echo "*/1 * * * * chmod -R 755 /Path/To/Directory/*") | crontab -`

This will add a Cronjob that will set every file in your folder to 755, every minute. (Might not be your intended answer but it will work i think)